# RestKit iOS tutorial - Xcode doesn't recognize a RestKit class method - missing framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I'm trying to follow the tutorial (link below) step-by-step to learn how to use RestKit and Core Data with my iOS app. When I get to the 6:13 mark in the video, I'm trying to initialize my RKManagedObjectStore object with the method objectStoreWithStoreFilename, and Xcode gives me an error saying there is no known class method for objectStoreWithStoreFilename. Is this due to a RestKit update, or am I missing a library/framework that allows me to use this method?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFi9t8NW0oY

Comment: If you setup the cocoapod correctly then you should have the correct version. Verify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in your .pch file to put `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` BEFORE `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`. It won't work if the order is the other way around.